# How to print the message for the smaller integer 1st?

Tags: c++

I am trying to have my program print the message for the smallest integer 1st while displaying whether both integers are odd or even? 
Program: 
First I have the user enter in 1 integer and then a second integer and it should display the smallest integer first and whether it is odd or even and then display the 2nd integer and whether it is odd or even.
My program is only displaying the smallest integer and whether it is odd or even but not both?

```
if (number1 > number2)
```

Comment: Why is the condition for your `if` and `else if` the same?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have the same condition for both `if`s, so the second one will never happen.
Second, you only output the information for one number in the branch you took.

You would need this structure:

```
if (number1 < number2)
{
    show info for number1
    show info for number2
}
else
{
    show info for number2
    show info for number1
}
show info for sum
```

But this is a bit unwieldy and error-prone.
Instead you can arrange the numbers in order first:

```
if (number1 > number2)
{
    std::swap(number1, number2);
}
show info for number1
show info for number2
show info for sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (number1 < number2)
{

    if (number1 % 2 == 0)
        cout << number1 << " is even.\n";
    else
        cout << number1 << " is odd.\n";
    if (number2 % 2 == 0)
        cout << number2 << " is even.\n";
    else
        cout << number2 << " is odd.\n";
}
else 
{
    if (number2 % 2 == 0)
        cout << number2 << " is even.\n";
    else
        cout << number2 << " is odd.\n";
    if (number1 % 2 == 0)
        cout << number1 << " is even.\n";
    else
        cout << number1 << " is odd.\n";
}
```

Coding can be done by calling separate functions.

Comment: *"Coding can be done by calling separate functions."* What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: If else code can be kept in separate functions and can be called. Solution provided for easy understanding. If OP wants can put if-else in two functions.